# How to navigate to another chart with same title/series name by clicking on a particular bar in a bar chart?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

In my Angular TS application, I have a bar chart with multiple series. Directly below the bar chart, there will be at least 100 scatter plots. The number of categories in the bar chart corresponds to the number of scatter plots, and each category is actually the title of the scatter plot. (These charts are rendered on the same page).

What I would like to know is whether is it possible for a user to click on a particular bar in the bar chart first, and he will be automatically redirected to the specific scatter plot with the category as its title? Since there will be > 100 scatter plots, I would want to save the user some time by having to scroll through all the scatter plots.

Of course, I know there is always the option of using ctrl-f to search for it. But is it possible with Angular + Highcharts?

Comment: can you provide some image or sample code?

Comment: Could you provide a basic template with really sample data to visualize your description? It will be much easier to find a solution.